# WiFI connection keeps disconnecting

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I have a small USB dongle that I use to connect to the network. For some reason it constantly keeps disconnecting without ever registering a valid IP address.

This is what first happens.

[image]

Then it suddenly disconnects and goes to this

[image]

and then these

[image]
[image]

and then goes back to the first screen.

I notice that it never actually registers an IP address. I can't figure out why this is happening.

This whole cycle keeps happening in about 3 second intervals. it connects, then disconnects and then connects again.

I am using Raspbian and this wifi adapter: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00EZOQFHO/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try with a powered usb hub.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but for anyone else looking - what worked for me was to change my router authentication settings. It was setup as WPA2-PSK. I had to change the Encryption Algorithm from TKIP and AES to just AES. On the rpi settings, the encryption is CCMP. This worked with a 5V 1A wall wart, USB key/mouse and Bluetooth adapter all plugged in a B+ without an extra USB hub. Also triple check that the passphrase is correct.

Comment: this works....unfortunately dont know why this works..but this seems kind of code bug

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and mine was just a matter of not having enough power. Once I unplugged my backlit keyboard the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to disable wifi security in your router and wifi dongle to check if it works.

If it does, then you can play with various wifi security settings.

If it does not work with wifi security disabled, then your wifi dongle is fuzzy or you power supply does not provide enough power.