# Raspberry Pi keeps disconnecting / restarting?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero-w

I've looked around here but couldn't find an answer that worked for me and I tried quite a few different things. `dmesg`, `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, etc.

I've also checked my security options are just `WPA2-PSK [AES]` as per [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26047/126983).

I'm tracking my Raspberry Pi's connection/disconnection. It's powered by a trustworthy power source (one that came with the raspberry pi and plugs to the mains).

This is a raspberry pi zero W that I keep connected to use with [room assistant](https://github.com/mKeRix/room-assistant) so it's basically getting Bluetooth information and passing back to my home assistant via MQTT.

Every now and then it will disconnect as you can see here:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me debug this to see what is going on and why it keeps on doing that. This PI is literally sat on top of my router so I don't imagine it's struggling to get to the wifi.

Thanks

Comment: Baffled - do you mean its disconnecting from Wifi / Bluetooth / Application / MQTT???

Comment: "restarting" pretty much implies a power supply problem.

Comment: Check the Raspberry Pi forum there's a new WiFi blob that should improve that and prevent disconnects.

Comment: Hey, @Dougie can you please link to it? I found some for the Pi 3 and the new Pi, but not the Pi Zero W. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would first pop in a freshly-formatted OS SD card and check if the issue is persisting then. That will help with initial debugging. Then you can determine if it's an issue with pi, router or the software that you're running currently.